# do_shortcode not working inside function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add shortcode after woocommerce content using the below code.
But echo do_shortcode is not working inside function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_banner', 12 );
    function custom_single_product_banner() {
    if(get_field('product_tree')){ 
    $field = the_field('product_tree');
    echo do_shortcode($field);
    };

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$field`?

Comment: Are you getting the value of get_field('product_tree') there? Also please try to assign the result of do_shortcode to a variable and return that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_banner', 12 );
    function custom_single_product_banner($result) { $pageid = get_the_ID();
    if(get_field('product_tree',$pageid)){ 
    $field = get_field('product_tree',$pageid);
    $result = do_shortcode($field);
    };
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please also ensure that the field value for product_tree is a shortcode.